# How do I resolve `Error: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` which occurs when adding many layers to Mapbox?

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js

I'm unsure if this is a bug in Mapbox GL JS (0.44.0), so I've filed an issue [here](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/6086).

The problem that I'm having is that some of my maps don't display the encoded polyline layers & output an error to the console.

The error as reported in Chrome:

```
evented.js:109 Error: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Actor.receive (actor.js:81)
Evented.fire @ evented.js:109
```

The error as reported in Safari:

```
[Error] Error: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.
receive — actor.js:81
[native code]

    fire (mapbox-gl.js:521:1250)
    fire (mapbox-gl.js:521:1091)
    fire (mapbox-gl.js:521:1091)
    (anonymous function) (mapbox-gl.js:199:1411)
    (anonymous function) (mapbox-gl.js:199:2541)
    receive (mapbox-gl.js:501:894)
    (anonymous function)
```

I don't know how to go about debugging this error.

#### Steps to Trigger Behavior

1. Visit https://citystrides.com/users/5560/map with Safari or Chrome on a Mac (I don't have a Windows computer to test with, and the page loads successfully with Firefox)
2. The base Mapbox map loads, but the red lines do not
3. View the console & see the error

Compared to a functional page...

1. Visit https://citystrides.com/users/1/map
2. View base Mapbox map along with the red lines

#### Relevant Site Code

While all of this code is available within the page source itself, I've included the relevant section of code I'm using to generate this view below for easier review.
The `<%= raw @encoded_polylines %>;` bit is an array of many encoded polylines as constructed within my Rails app. You can view that raw data [here](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/files/1691906/polylines.txt).

```
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'TOKEN';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: 'map',
  style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v10',
  center: center_value,
  zoom: zoom_value
});
map.addControl(new mapboxgl.NavigationControl(), 'top-left');

var encodedPolylines  = <%= raw @encoded_polylines %>;
var arrayLength       = encodedPolylines.length;
var featureCollection = [];

for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
  featureCollection.push({
    type: 'Feature',
    geometry: polyline.toGeoJSON(encodedPolylines[i])
  });
}

map.on('style.load', function(){
  map.addSource('polylineCollection', {
    type: 'geojson',
    data: {
      type: 'FeatureCollection',
      features: featureCollection
    }
  });
  map.addLayer({
    id: 'polylineCollection',
    type: 'line',
    source: 'polylineCollection',
    layout: {
      'line-join': 'round',
      'line-cap': 'round'
    },
    paint: {
      'line-color': '#DD251E',
      'line-width': 2
    }
  });
});
```

#### Further Details

- The number of layers or the size of the data don't appear to be factors. While I *am* attempting to draw hundreds of these layers on the page, I have some users with more / much larger layers where the map & encoded polylines draw just fine.
- I'm thinking it could be a matter of **data integrity** - perhaps the non-functional user has one/some encoded polylines that are 'broken' somehow.
- I tried putting the `addSource`/`addLayer` calls within the `for` loop, in order to watch the map load layer by layer ... Those calls seem to be async, though, so while I still see many of the encoded polylines draw before seeing the same error appear - I can't figure out how to determine *which* layer caused the error.
- In my debugging, I *did* find that the error is occurring during the `addSource` call. I found this by commenting the `addLayer` call & still seeing the error.

#### Requests

- Do you see an obvious issue here?
- Is there a way to 'validate' geoJSON data?
- Can you share suggested debugging approaches? I'm having a very hard time pinpointing exactly which item causes the error because it all occurs async...

Answer (score 0):

I played around with the `for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {` line a bit, in order to walk through smaller portions of the overall data set. The `arrayLength` value was 327, so I swapped out a hard-coded value of *around* half that at 150:

`for (var i = 0; i < 150; i++) {`

That also failed, so I backed down by roughly half again at 75:

`for (var i = 0; i < 75; i++) {`

This succeeded, so I chose a number ~halfway between 75-150 & repeated that approach for a bit... Eventually I got to a small enough range that I could step through them one by one without using the `for` loop & just setting specific hard-coded values of `i`. For example:

```
featureCollection.push({
  type: 'Feature',
  geometry: polyline.toGeoJSON(encodedPolylines[102])
});
```

I eventually found that there was a bogus encoded polyline value for that activity. So, it all points to bad data at this point.

I still have the lingering question of whether or not encoded polylines / geoJSON data can be 'validated' somehow...